# SQLite: How to write a query which would fill empty cells in resultset

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite db table with the following schema and sample data:

```
  Fruit|  LBS|  Time
-----------------------
  Apple|       1|  00001
  Apple|       2|  00002
 Orange|       1|  00001
 Banana|       3|  00004
```

And I'd like to be able to run a query to distribute/overload one column, namely "Fruit" against another column, "Time" and derive at a resultset with an inflated/filled in (default) values as such:

```
  Fruit|     LBS|  Time
-----------------------
  Apple|       1|  00001
  Apple|       2|  00002
  Apple|       0|  00004
 Orange|       1|  00001
 Orange|       0|  00002
 Orange|       0|  00004
 Banana|       0|  00001
 Banana|       0|  00002
 Banana|       3|  00004
```

As you can see the all existing values for Time is repeated for each of the unique Fruit types with default (empty) values.

I apologize for not knowing exactly what this is called; but I hope this example gets my point across.

Comment: LBS and Time are always the same? If LBS=1,TIME=00001 for Apple, and LBS=1,TIME=123456 for Orange, and you miss Banana,1 which value do you need to show for Banana, 00001 or 123456?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    f.Fruit, 
    COALESCE(x.LBS, 0), 
    t.Time 
FROM ( 
               ( SELECT DISTINCT Fruit FROM your_table ) f 
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT Time  FROM your_table ) t 
) 
LEFT JOIN your_table x 
    ON  f.Fruit = x.Fruit 
    AND t.Time = x.Time;
```